# How to calculate "modular multiplicative inverse" when the denominator is not co-prime with m?

Tags: numbers, modulo, largenumber

I need to calculate **`(a/b) mod m`** where **`a`** and **`b`** are very large numbers.

What I am trying to do is to calculate **`(a mod m) * (x mod m)`**, where **`x`** is the [modular inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of **`b`**.

I tried using [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), but what to do when b and m are not co-prime?
It is specifically [mentioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Computation) that b and m need to be co-prime.

I tried using the code [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Formal_description_of_the_algorithm), and realized that for example:
**`3 * x mod 12`** is not at all possible for any value of **`x`**, it does not exist!

**What should I do?** Can the algorithm be modified somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, you are in trouble.  x has no solution in `b*x = 1 mod m` if b and m have a common divisor.  Similarly, in your original problem `a/b = y mod m`, you are looking for y such that `a=by mod m`.  If a is divisible by `gcd(b,m)`, then you can divide out by that factor and solve for y.  If not, then there is no y that can solve the equation (i.e. `a/b mod m` is not defined).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If a is divisible by gcd(b,m), then you can solve it.  Otherwise, the divide operation isn't even defined.  You'd need to figure out another way to achieve your ultimate objective without modular division.

Comment: I mean, what can be the other ways to "achieve my ultimate objective without modular division"?

Comment: @eSKay your question doesn't make sense. What is your ultimate objective?

Comment: Why are you doing modular division in the first place?  I presume there is some task (a.k.a. ultimate objective) you're trying to perform using modular division as a subroutine.  What is that task?  Methinks that whatever it is, modular division probably isn't the answer.

Comment: @Keith Randall  yep, you are right. what I am trying to do is to caculate the mod of a series of the form 1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n % m. I mentioned a/b form because I tried to use the geometric sum formula. iterating the entire series id not an option as n is very very large (~10^17)

Comment: You could evaluate k_i = 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{i-1} % m with a recursive formula:
k_1 = 1
k_2i = k_i + x^i * k_i % m

Compute x^i with a repeated squaring algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_squaring).

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it a bit more you might still be ok.  It should always be the case that a is divisible by gcd(b,m) with the numbers you're using (a = 1-x^{n+1}, b = 1-x).  However, if gcd(b,m)>1, then the results of the division are not unique - you identify the result mod m/gcd(b,m).  I don't know if there's an easy way to figure out which of the gcd(b,m) possibilities is the right one without computing your sum from scratch.

Comment: @Lazer: If calculating a geometric series modulo m is your objective, then [this link](http://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-just-simple-sum#Back_to_the_geometric_series) could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that b and m have to be coprime is because of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Basically the problem:

`3 * x mod 12`

Can be thought of as a compound problem involving

`3*x mod 3` and `3*x mod 4 = 2^2`

Now if b is not coprime to 12, this is like trying to divide by zero. Thus the answer doesn't exist!

This is due to field theory in abstract algebra. A field is basically a set which has addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division well-defined. A finite field is always of the form GF(p^n), where p is prime and n is a positive integer, and the operations are addition and multiplication modulo p^n. Now, 12 is not a prime power, so your *ring* is not a field. Thus this problem can't be solved for any b which is not coprime to m.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~sarah/magic/topics/division
It might help.
It explains methods of modular division.